# How to process files in pairs

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I need to process files in couples.
So if I have:

```
00000.nii.gz   
00001.nii.gz
00002.nii.gz
00003.nii.gz
```

and so on... (`nii.gz` is an extension used during imaging resonance processing) I need to process the file `00000.nii.gz` and `00001.nii.gz` together, then `0002.nii.gz` and `00003.nii.gz` and so on. For each output, I need to rename it.

Comment: Are these files in a directory or do you have a list of them?

Comment: What does "couples" mean here? Do you need to handle some sets of files in groups, or just perform the same process on each file individually and independently? For the latter, `for f in *; do`, see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals#Conditional_Loops_.28while.2C_until_and_for.29

Comment: The files are in a directory, you can call it just db.dir

Comment: Bu couple I mean that I need to perform the same process for like 00000.nii.gz and 00001.nii.gz and than the same process for the couple 00002.nii.gz with 0003.nii.gz and so on

Comment: What renaming would you need to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the number in the file names are five-digit zero-filled numbers and that the occasional four-digit string in the question and in the comments are typos.

```
#!/bin/bash

for (( i = 0; i <= 99999; i += 2 )); do
    name1=$( printf '%05d.nii.gz' "$i" )
    name2=$( printf '%05d.nii.gz' "$(( i + 1 ))" )

    if [ -f "$name1" ] && [ -f "$name2" ]; then
        printf 'Processing "%s" and "%s" together...\n' "$name1" "$name2" >&2
        # use the two files here
    else
        printf '"%s" or "%s" not found, exiting.\n' "$name1" "$name2" >&2
        break
    fi
done
```

The loop goes from zero to a large number in increments of two.  For each iteration, it constructs the two filenames using the variable `i` in two calls to `printf` (once for `i` and once for `i+1`).  The format specifier `%05d` formats an integer to a zero-filled five-digit string.

As soon as the constructed filenames no longer corresponds to any existing files (in the current directory), the loop exits.

If the files are located in another directory than in the current, change the `printf` format string from `'%05d.nii.gz'` to `'/path/to/dir/%05d.nii.gz'`.

---

To keep with the DRY principle ("Don't Repeat Yourself"):

```
#!/bin/bash

dir='/path/to/dir'
name_fmt="$dir/%05d.nii.gz"

for (( i = 0; i <= 99999; i += 2 )); do
    name1=$( printf "$name_fmt" "$i" )
    name2=$( printf "$name_fmt" "$(( i + 1 ))" )

    if [ -f "$name1" ] && [ -f "$name2" ]; then
        printf 'Processing "%s" and "%s" together...\n' "$name1" "$name2" >&2
        # use the two files here
    else
        printf '"%s" or "%s" not found, exiting.\n' "$name1" "$name2" >&2
        break
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thx for the help, I need to try this script. by the way, the files are named like this:  dr_stage2_subject00000.nii.gz , then  dr_stage2_subject00001.nii.gz and so on

Comment: @user277297 Then change `name_fmt` in my last code piece to `dr_stage2_subject%05d.nii.gz` (possibly with a directory path in front).

Comment: #!/bin/bash

dir='/project/3013056.01/Test/dual_regression.dr'
name_fmt="$dir/dr_stage2_subject%05d.nii.gz"

for (( i = 0; i <= 99999; i += 2 )); do
    name1=$( printf "$dr_stage2_subject%05d.nii.gz" "$i" )
    name2=$( printf "$dr_stage2_subject%05d.nii.gz" "$(( i + 1 ))" )

    if [ -f "$name1" ] && [ -f "$name2" ]; then
        printf 'Processing "%s" and "%s" together...\n' "$name1" "$name2" >&2
        fslmaths $name1 -sub $name2 
    else
        printf '"%s" or "%s" not found, exiting.\n' "$name1" "$name2" >&2
        break
    fi
done

Comment: But it gives me this error"00000.nii.gz" or "00001.nii.gz" not found, exiting.

Comment: @user277297 You have combined my two solutions. Only look at the second one if that makes it easier. The two `printf` calls that generate the filenames should look exactly like I have them in my code, using `$name_fmt` and not `$dr_...` (you are inserting a nonexistent variable here, which is why it doesn't work for you).

Comment: Ok great but how do I set an output filename? By the way, thx a lot for the help  and to @drl

Comment: @user277297 I was wondering about that in a comment to the question. You said something about renaming files, but you never explained that part.  If you add `>output` just after `done` (`done >output`) then the output produced in the loop will be written to a file called `output`.

Comment: every couple (dr_stage2_00000.nii.gz and dr_stage_00001.nii.gz) produces an output (let's call it sub_1), then the next couple will produce an output, called sub_2 and so on. I want to save each output with a different name (again sub_1,sub_2 and so on).

Comment: @user277297 Then do the redirection after the `fslmaths` utility ta a filename that contains `$i`: `fslmaths ...other options... >"sub_$i"`.  This will create output files called `sub_0`, `sub_2` etc. since the loop increments `i` by two in each iteration.

Comment: #!/bin/bash

dir='/project/3013056.01/Test/dual_regression.dr'
name_fmt="$dir/dr_stage2_subject%05d.nii.gz"

for (( i = 0; i <= 99999; i += 2 )); do
    name1=$( printf "$name_fmt" "$i" )
    name2=$( printf "$name_fmt" "$(( i + 1 ))" )

    if [ -f "$name1" ] && [ -f "$name2" ]; then
        printf 'Processing "%s" and "%s" together...\n' "$name1" "$name2" >&2
        fslmaths $name1 -sub $name2 $i: fslmaths ...other options... >"sub_$i
    else
        printf '"%s" or "%s" not found, exiting.\n' "$name1" "$name2" >&2
        break
    fi
done

Comment: it gives me this error: sub.sh: line 14: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
sub.sh: line 18: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: @user277297 Well, you have `>"sub_$i` with no ending `"`.  That should be `>"sub_$i"`.  And I used `...other options...` as a _placeholder_ in my text to not have to write out the options that you had. Don't include that in the code.

Comment: the outputs are in the txt file and even if I set the right file extension (.nii.gz) the program fsleyes cannot open it

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you had a number of files like this:

```
echo z?
z1 z2 z3 z4 z5 z6 z7 z8 z9
```

Then to get couples, you could use:

```
echo z? | xargs -n2
z1 z2
z3 z4
z5 z6
z7 z8
z9
```

To get triples:

```
echo z? | xargs -n3
z1 z2 z3
z4 z5 z6
z7 z8 z9
```

The default command for xargs is echo, but you can supply your own command. The man page for xargs, while long, includes a few examples at the end.

Best wishes ... cheers, drl